# Why isn't my music syncing from itunes to my ipod?

Tags: itunes, icloud, data-synchronization, ipod-touch, ipod

I recently got a replacement Ipod touch 5. I restored it and got all of my songs off of icloud. However. Songs I didn't purchase (such as being downloaded from CDs) are in my itunes library on my computer. I have synced my ipod to the computer multiple times with all the songs checked but it only transferred three songs. The rest have a circled '!' on the left and will not show up. How do I get my songs from my library onto my ipod. So I only have what was purchased through itunes on my new ipod.

Answer (score 1):

Can you play the songs on iTunes? The exclamation mark means iTunes can't find the file associated with that song. Maybe you moved it or it was deleted, or it lived on another hard drive. The solution is to locate the files for your songs first, and then either re-import them into iTunes or re-link them in iTunes. More information here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1408